# Scaling and panning image from center orgin using ScrollViewer is not working in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

My requirement is, I would like to zoom a image programmatically by using scrollviewer ZoomToFactor method. And when applying zoom value using ZoomToFactor method, it should be zoom from center of the orgin.

So, i have added image in a grid layout and set it's horizontal and vertical alignment as center, then added grid with in a ScrollViewer as you see in the below code snippet.

[XAML]

```
<ContentControl  Grid.Row="2">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"  ZoomMode="Enabled"  >

        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="216" Height="319">
            <Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="Assets\EditedImage.jpg" />
        </Grid>

    </ScrollViewer>
</ContentControl>
```

[C#]

```
 int count = 1;
 private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                count += 1;
                scrollViewer.ZoomToFactor(count);            
            }
```

Issue-1: Image was zoomed from topLeft position. But is should be zoomed from center of the image.

Issue-2: After zoom-in, if you pan horizontally using finger, it reset to previous position.

Also, i tried RenderTransformOrigin as (0.5, 0.5) to Grid and Image in above code. That also failed.

[Sample link:](https://github.com/bharathirajauk/MySamples/blob/master/ScrollViewer.zip)

Any one, please guide me what is wrong with above code.

Regards,

Bharathi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Scaling and panning image from center orgin using ScrollViewer is not working in UWP

I have tested above code, the problem use you place the `ScrollViewer` in the [`ContentControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentcontrol?view=winrt-19041) that cause the `ScrollViewer` size same as child Grid size. You could use `UserControl` to replace.

```
<UserControl  Grid.Row="2">
    <ScrollViewer  x:Name="scrollViewer"   VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"  ZoomMode="Enabled"   >
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="216" Height="319" >
            <Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="Assets\EditedImage.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is working. Also need to use ChangeView(width/2, height/2, scale); instead of ZoomToFactor method. It was deprecated and has some issue after some zooming

Comment: When increase scale level 0.1 every time, it is not working. Can you please provide solution for this.?

Comment: Sure, May I check this tomorrow, because  I am off duty soon.

Comment: Ok. Thank you.. I will wait.

Comment: I resolved it partially by scrollviewer.ScrollableWidth and Height. But it is not provide exact solution. Please refer the below post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63503044/scaling-image-from-center-orgin-using-scrollviewer-is-not-working-in-uwp