# Scaling image from center orgin using ScrollViewer is not working in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, scrollviewer

I am using scroll viewer to zoom the image which is set as background for Grid.When, I am setting the zoom level value on button click from code behind with scrollViewer.ChangeView(horizontalOffset,verticalOffset,zoomFactor) image is getting zoomed from Top left corner ,not from the center position.When increasing scale level as 0.1 every time in the button click.

Find the sample here:[Sample](https://github.com/ragulsv/ScrollViewer)

XAML:

```
        <UserControl  Grid.Row="2">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"  ZoomMode="Enabled"  >

            <Grid x:Name="ImageGrid" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="1260" Height="350" >
                <Image x:Name="MyImage" Width="1260" Height="210" Source="Assets\EditedImage.jpg" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" />
            </Grid>

        </ScrollViewer>
    </UserControl>
```

C#:

```
    float count = 1;
    private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        count += 0.1f;
        var width = this.scrollViewer.ExtentWidth / 2;
        var height = this.scrollViewer.ExtentHeight  / 2;

        scrollViewer.ChangeView(width, height, count);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must calculate the offset relative to the scrollable area.

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel>
  <Button Click="ZoomIn_OnButtonClick" Content="Increase Zoom"/>
  <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" 
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
    <Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="Assets\golden_eaglew.jpg" />
  </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

### Solution using `ScrollViewer.ChangeView`

Since the scroll viewer's extent changes as a result of applying the zoom and the zoom is applied *after* the scroll offsets are applied, you have to defer the scrolling to the center by making use of the `ScrollViewer.ViewChanged` event. This is because the scrollable area is influenced by the extent's size (e.g. `ScrollableWidth` = `ExtentWidth` - `ViewportWidth`).

```
public MainPage()
{
  this.InitializeComponent(); 

  this.ScrollViewer.ViewChanged += ScrollToCenterOnScrollViewerChanged;
}

private void ScrollToCenterOnScrollViewerChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.IsIntermediate)
  {
    return;
  }

  var scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
  scrollViewer.ChangeView(
    scrollViewer.ScrollableWidth / 2, 
    scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight / 2, 
    null);
}

private void ZoomIn_OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
  => this.ScrollViewer.ChangeView(null, null, this.ScrollViewer.ZoomFactor + 0.1f);
```

---

### Alternative Solution 1: use `ScrollViewer.ZoomToFactor`

Note that this API is [marked as deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.zoomtofactor?view=winrt-19041) and is not guaranteed to be available in future framework versions.

```
private void ZoomIn_OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
  this.ScrollViewer.ZoomToFactor(this.ScrollViewer.ZoomFactor + 0.1f);
  this.ScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(this.ScrollViewer.ScrollableWidth / 2);
  this.ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(this.ScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight / 2);
}
```

---

### Alternative Solution 2: implement a custom `ZoomToFactor` method

```
private void ZoomToFactor(double zoomFactor, ScrollViewer scrollViewer)
{
  if (!(scrollViewer?.Content is FrameworkElement zoomTarget))
  {
    return;
  }

  // Apply the zoom to the scroll content
  zoomTarget.Width = zoomTarget.ActualWidth * zoomFactor;
  zoomTarget.Height = zoomTarget.ActualHeight * zoomFactor;

  // Scroll the zoomed scroll content to center
  var scaledScrollableWidth = scrollViewer.ExtentWidth * zoomFactor - scrollViewer.ViewportWidth);
  var scaledScrollableHeight = scrollViewer.ExtentHeight * zoomFactor - scrollViewer.ViewportHeight;
  double horizontalScrollCenterOffset = scaledScrollableWidth / 2;
  double verticalScrollCenterOffset = scaledScrollableHeight / 2;

  scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(horizontalScrollCenterOffset);
  scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(verticalScrollCenterOffset);
}

// Usage example
private void ZoomIn_OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
  ZoomToFactor(1.1, this.ScrollViewer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had tried this approach ,it is working partially. I am expecting a  accurate center positioning. Can you check and help me out this?

Comment: Sorry, I was afk. I have just updated the solution to provide a smoother experience.

Comment: Thanks BionicCode, ZoomToFactor is deprectated one , can you provide a solution based on the ChangeView?

Comment: Thanks, I had checked your solution **ZoomToFactor** is working as expected. But, while using **ChangeView** it is not positioning in center intially. Can you provide a solution for this?

Comment: `ChangeView` is executed in at least two passes. After zoom was applied the scroll viewer's extend changes. This affects the scrollable area e.g. `ExtentWidth - ViewportWidth = ScrollableWidth`. This why you have to subscribe to the `ScrollViewer.ViewChanged` event which is raised after the zooming occurred. Inside this event handler you scroll to the center using the updated scroll area. I'am not sure if I understood your right. The first zoom doesn't center the image, but every subsequent zoom does?

Comment: Yes, But I need to center the image in first zoom itself like **ZoomToFactor** solution.

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide a third solution. It implements a custom `ZoomToFactor`, so that you can get rid of the dependency to the deprecated API.